# Bernoulli distribution question

Tags: probability

$X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $\mathrm{Pr}(X=1)= p = 0.99$.

$Y$ is distributed $N(0,1)$. $W$ is distributed $N(0,100)$ and $X, Y, W$ are independent.

Let $S=XY+(1-X)W$, that is $S=Y$ when $X=1$ and $S=W$ when $X=0$.

a) Show that $E(Y^2)=1$ and $E(W^2)=100$.

b) Show that $E(Y^3)=0$ and $E(W^3)=0$.

Comment: Your question does not make sense because you defined $X$ and $S$ but never use them in your question. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Those are for the questions c and d. I only need the solutions of a and b.

Comment: So please do not define them in your post. The first two questions are about [computing the moments of a gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moments of $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ are
$$\mathbb{E}[Z^n] = 
\begin{cases}
\sigma^n(n-1)!!\quad&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is even}\\
0\quad&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is odd}\\
\end{cases}$$
You should check the [following post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92648/calculation-of-the-n-th-central-moment-of-the-normal-distribution-mathcaln). Your questions sets $n=2,3$ and $\sigma^2 = 1,100$.

Comment: Thank u so much for your help.

Comment: Can you please help me out on these two as well? Derive E(S), E(S^2), E(S^3) and E(S^4). Hint: Use the law of iterated expectations conditioning on X=0 and X=1.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Please create another question.